# AWS SQS - when will the duplicated message arrive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, fifo

I understand that standard SQS uses "at least once" delivery while FIFO messages are delivered exactly once. I'm trying to weigh standard queues vs FIFO for my application, and one factor is how long it takes for the duplicated message to arrive.

I intend to consume messages from SQS then post the data I received to an idempotent third-party API. I understand that with standard SQS, there's always a risk of me overwriting more recent data with the old duplicated data.

For example:

```
Message A arrives, I post it onwards.
Message A duplicate arrives, I post it onwards.
Message B arrives, I post it onwards.
All fine ✓
```

On the other hand:

```
Message A arrives, I post it onwards.
Message B arrives, I post it onwards.
Message A duplicate arrives - I post it and overwrite the latest data, which was B! ✖
```

I want to measure this risk, i.e. I want to know how long the duplicate message should take to arrive. Will the duplicate message take roughly the same amount of time to arrive, as the original message?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's useful to understand how message duplication occurs. As far as I know this isn't documented in the official docs, but instead it's **my mental model** of how it works. **This is an educated guess.**

Whenever you send a message to SQS (`SendMessage` API), this message arrives at the SQS webservice endpoint, which is one of probably thousands of servers. This endpoint receives your message, duplicates it one or more times and stores these duplicates on more than one SQS server. After it has received confirmation from at least two SQS servers, it acknowledges to the client that the message has been received.

When you call the `ReceiveMessage` API only a subset of the SQS servers that handle your queue are queried for messages. When a message is returned, these servers communicate to their peers, that this message is currently in-flight and the visibility timeout starts. This doesn't happen instantaneously, as it's a distributed system. While this `ReceiveMessage` call takes place another consumer might also do a `ReceiveMessage` call and happen to query one of the servers that have a replica of the message, before it's marked as in-flight. That server hands out the message and now you have to consumers working on it.

This is just one scenario, which is the result of this being a distributed system.
There are a couple of edge cases that can happen as the result of network issues, e.g. when the SQS response to the initial `SendMessage` gets lost and the client thinks the message didn't arrive and sends it again - poof, you got another duplicate.

**The point being: things fail in weird and complex ways.** That makes measuring the risk of a delayed message difficult. If your use case can't handle duplicate and out of order messages, you should go for FIFO, but that will inherently limit your throughput. Alternatives are based on distributed locking mechanisms and keeping track of which messages you have already processed, which are complex tools to solve a complex problem.